# Replace string spaces with special characters

Tags: c++, string

My program is not replacing every character of special string into the spaces of the input string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

char *replacingSpaces(char s[]){

int last = 0, spacecount = 0;

char *sp = (char *) "$99";
int len = (int) strlen(s);
int lensp = (int) strlen(sp);

for(int i = 0;i<len;i++){
    if(s[i]==' ')spacecount++;
}
if(spacecount == 0) return s;

char *newStr = (char *) malloc((size_t) (spacecount*(lensp-1)+len+1));

for(int i = 0;i<len;i++){
    if(s[i]!=' '){
        newStr[last] = s[i];
        last++;

    }
    else{
        newStr[last] = sp[0];
        newStr[last] = sp[1];
        newStr[last] = sp[2];
        last++;

    }
 }
 newStr[last++] = '\0';


 return newStr;
 }

 int main(){

 char s[100] = "Replace spaces with special characters";
 cout << replacingSpaces(s) << endl;

 return 0;
 }
```

and the output of the program is as follows:

> Replace9spaces9with9special9characters

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? could you give a sample input and output. Thanks :)

Comment: input is the char s string from main(), i want to replace every space inside that stirng with $99

Comment: For your own sake, stop using C-style casts! The only cast necessary here is a `static_cast` to convert the returvalue of `malloc()`. In all other cases, you are just using the wrong type to store a value, which you shouldn't "fix" by brute-force converting the value to fit.

Comment: Thanks for the advise @UlrichEckhardt, i will keep that in mind! :)

Comment: @Willy You tagged this as C++, and I don't see any usage of C++ in the program.  This is a 4 or 5 line function in C++, not a `C` monstrosity using `malloc`.

Comment: Casting the returnvalue of `malloc()` is only necessary in C++, so this is surely not C. Also, `cout` doesn't exist in C either, @PaulMcKenzie.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I am talking about how the program is constructed.  It is constructed using C-style.  It doesn't even come close to how to succinctly do this in C++.  Casting `malloc` and using `cout` doesn't make it a suitable `C++` solution.  It even has a memory leak that isn't mentioned.

Comment: @Willy -- Look at this:  http://ideone.com/CWjQyH  Compare that to what you have.

Comment: Great! Thank you for pointing out all those mistakes @PaulMcKenzie.

Comment: @Willy Not really "mistakes", but what C++ gives you.  Note that you don't see any usage of pointers, and how small the code is.  The days of using `char *` and `malloc` to create strings, as well as writing boilerplate replacement routines from scratch are (or should be) few and far between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in you increment operator `last++`, You have to increment it inside `newStr[last]` :

```
for(int i = 0;i<len;i++){
    if(s[i]!=' '){
        newStr[last++] = s[i];


    }
    else{
        newStr[last++] = sp[0];
        newStr[last++] = sp[1];
        newStr[last++] = sp[2];

    }
 }
```

and why so many casts?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
else{
    newStr[last++] = sp[0];
    newStr[last++] = sp[1];
    newStr[last++] = sp[2];
}
```

It should work.

Comment: I reason i did not accept your answer was, you missed to do newStr[last++] inside for loop.. :)